# I have a .dd file stored inside a zip folder, how do I view its contents?

Tags: zip, disk-image

I have a .dd file stored inside a zip folder, how do I view its contents? I have tried many options, among which is the systools disk image viewer. Most of the tools I've tried once downloaded ask for a payment, but this one doesn't. Hence I thought it would work and did the following: I extracted the .dd from in the zip and then attempted to scan the extracted .dd but it says: "select proper file type". I am operating off windows. Could you please explain to me how to view the contents of the .dd?

Comment: (1) I am able to store binary noise as a file with any extension. Its existence will not imply its meaningfulness. Where did your file come from? (2) Did you use the `dd-wrt` tag knowingly because there's a connection with DD-WRT? What connection then? (3) In some sense you can view contents of *any* file with a [binary editor](https://superuser.com/q/1055977/432690) or a [text editor](https://superuser.com/q/369231/432690). Is this what you want? (4) If not, you need [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) first. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/272338/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the reason I used the dd-wrt tag, is because it is a .dd file, is this not correct?

Comment: as far as viewing it from a text editor goes, it returns a ton of incomprehensible writing when I try to open it on notepad

Comment: See the [info about the tag](https://superuser.com/tags/dd-wrt/info).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sorry about that, I'll remove the tag thanks for picking me up on the error

Comment: Is there some form of free software I can use, to view the content of the file?

Comment: "A ton of incomprehensible writing when I try to open it on notepad" is expected for binary files (and binary noise). To be clear: with editors (especially binary editors) you can *view* the content of the file. But probably you want a program that can *interpret* this type of file, whatever the type is. One should choose a program according to the type. You may or may not be able to learn the type by running the `file` command in Linux/Unix or some equivalent in Windows. That's why I gave you the links. What does `file` say about your file?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm trying to find a way to rung it on windows, but I'm not managing to find a way. I've looked for it on google, but I can't seem to find it. Do you have any ideas on what I can do on windows?

Comment: Beside the [link I already gave you](https://superuser.com/q/272338/432690) – no. Nevertheless I still believe a generic tool (like `file`) to recognize the type is the right first step. If you manage to get some information about your file from such tool then please [edit] the question and put the information there. Note seeking product recommendations is off-topic, so avoid asking "what program?"; it's OK to ask "how can I?" instead. And I think the word "interpret" is better than "view" in this case. I may be able to help after you find the type. Good luck.

Comment: Note: sometimes one can *guess* the type, knowing where the file came from, what the purpose of it is and what it is supposed to be. Do you know anything like this about the file in question?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think it came from some form of CTF challenge

Comment: My employer's son often asks him to ask me such questions, and well this time I don't know the answer and hence I'm trying to find it :)

Comment: Without further information (like from `file`) I can only give you this: sometimes people use the `.dd` extension for images of block devices. It's somewhat connected to the `dd` Unix tool [one can use to create an image or write it back](https://superuser.com/q/944603/432690). But one can use `dd` for other things, so this extension makes almost as little sense as using `.cp` for any file because you can copy the file. Still it may be the file in question contains a filesystem or a structure with MBR, partition table and filesystem(s). I would know what to try in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When someone tells me about a dd-file I associate this with "Disk Dump". I would expect that to be an image file of a disk - like Kamil Maciorowski described it in the comment section.

There are various possibilities to make the content visible.

**Option 1 - use a software to mount image files**

There is free software around that mounts image files in Windows so that the image file appears to the operating system as a disk. If that file contains valid structures, a Windows operating system should be able to read its contents then.
Search for "mount image file".

**Option 2 - use a software that reads out image files**

This is your current choice that failed!
Some disk editors and forensic editors are able to handle a disk image like the source it was pulled from. Such a tool would tell you for instance, that there are a number of partitions in there und would be able to read directories in there and extract files.

If your "systools disk image viewer refuses to work stating "select proper file type" then your image is lacking the structure the image viewer is expecting.

The reason is that the content could be something different or that the image is not a full disk image but only a partition image. A partition image would directly start with a boot sector. Such a structure is called "supper floppy" and the editor has to be able to identify this structure.

**Option 3 - Put the image file back onto a drive**

Another way would be to write this dd file to USB stick or hdd or ssd (not sure if Rufus supports hdds and ssds as well) using a tool such as Rufus in the windows world.
Then you really have a disk drive (the USB stick) and your operating system should be able to read it.

Use a hex editor to look at unknown files. Text editors most likely fail or take very long when dealing with long files as they try to read the whole file in memory.